# How to calculate balances by selecting max transaction_date of every row from different transaction date in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I need to query, every customers Max transaction_date sow within that transaction date, i can find the balance of that customer also i need to find only balance customers.

here is the picture of my database

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4LiNRzY7JjvcU5OVlJsWHpORzQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: For sql server or Mysql?

Comment: Can u cut and paste create statements. Sample data expected results

Comment: did you follow the above link, in the down side i described wanted result.

Comment: @AsConfused

` Bill_no   customer_id    Balance
68   12            100
70   10            1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  b1.customer_id,
  b1.balance
FROM
  bills b1
  JOIN (
         -- sub query to get max transaction_date for each customer
         SELECT
          customer_id,
          MAX(transaction_date) AS MaxDate
         FROM
          Bills
         GROUP BY
          customer_id
       ) b2
    ON b2.customer_id = b1.customer_id
       AND b2.MaxDate = b1.transaction_date
WHERE
  b1.balance <> 0
```

This is sufficient for your data, however you may want to add a date range with a `WHERE` clause in the sub-query when the data ranges over a greater number of rows..

Answer (score 0):

```
drop table theData;

create table theData
(
billno int not null auto_increment primary key,
customer_id int not null,
balance decimal(14,2) not null,
transaction_date datetime not null
);

insert theData (customer_id,balance,transaction_date) values (11,33,'2014-05-01');
insert theData (customer_id,balance,transaction_date) values (11,22,'2014-07-01');
insert theData (customer_id,balance,transaction_date) values (11,0,'2014-08-01');

insert theData (customer_id,balance,transaction_date) values (12,3,'2014-02-01');
insert theData (customer_id,balance,transaction_date) values (12,5,'2014-07-01');
insert theData (customer_id,balance,transaction_date) values (12,100,'2014-08-01');

insert theData (customer_id,balance,transaction_date) values (8,9999,'2013-01-01');
insert theData (customer_id,balance,transaction_date) values (8,882,'2013-02-03');
insert theData (customer_id,balance,transaction_date) values (8,0,'2013-08-02');

insert theData (customer_id,balance,transaction_date) values (10,6,'2014-07-02');
insert theData (customer_id,balance,transaction_date) values (10,1,'2014-08-02');

-- select * from theData;


SELECT t1.customer_id, 
t1.balance 
FROM theData t1
JOIN 
( -- sub query to get max transaction_date for each customer 
SELECT b1.customer_id, 
MAX(transaction_date) AS MaxDate 
FROM theData b1 
GROUP BY customer_id 
) b2 
ON b2.customer_id = t1.customer_id AND b2.MaxDate = t1.transaction_date
where t1.balance<>0
order by t1.customer_id


customer_id     balance
10              1.00
12              100.00
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH IT WORKS.. AND YOU SAVED ME A GOLDEN TIME, APPRICIATED....

i used INNER JOIN instead JOIN ONLY.... @ AsConfused

Comment: Thank @johnS i just cleaned up a few messes that can only be done with testing